# php read webpage after all processing are done

Tags: php, process

I dont know how to explain my need, and neither which key words to use to find a solution on google, so i'll give an url to be more clear: 
[check an IP](http://multirbl.valli.org/) (click on: Check your current IP address)

I'ld like, by using this website for example, getting somes informations after all the processus are terminated.

I tried with "file_get_contents" and with "cURL functions" but i did not find a way to do it, i always get the original source code.

Any idea ?

EDIT:

```
<body onLoad="setTimeout('get_my_blacklist()', 60000)">
...
...
<?php
echo '<iframe id="my_iframe" src="http://multirbl.valli.org/lookup/'.$ip.'.html">';
?>
...
...
<script>
function get_my_blacklist()
{
    //function to get the content after somes secondes.
}
</script>
```

Here is the new code i tried thank to @Ludovic for is iframe idea.
Still working on it, i'll tell you if its working or not to solve my issue.
Edit2: Whatever how i try, i didnt find a way to get the containt of my frame window.. And even if i'ld succeed, i dont know how i can update my database if do it with JQuery/Javascript

Comment: The subject doesn't illustrate your issue. Be more specific please. Also, what are you trying to get ("getting somes informations") and after which processus ("all the processus" is too vague).

Comment: @Zeratops sorry didnt saw yr comment... I try to get all the adresses where i'm "Listed", 'all the processus' are the work the website does to check if i'm listed or not on his servers list. It take like 45sec. If i'm right, it doing in client side, that's why i cant get thoses informations with file_get_content.

Comment: I don't know if you are aware of JQuery `$post()` function, which allow you to send a php file by this way and get the result. You can also pass some parameter to your php file sent and take back the result. Please check http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/ and let us know if it helped you.

Comment: @Zeratops Thank for your help. I know nothing of JQuery langage, i'll still try to do something with it.

Answer (score 0):

First the page should have been construct by server script like PHP, at this step you have all IP requested then the page is modified by JQuery script who seems to query each IP.
The second step is an asynchronous script so you can't know when the page is effectively finished to construct.

Comment: But is it possible to do something like 'opening' the webpage, doing a sleep(120) while my page is working, and then read the content ?

Comment: Yes you can try to know the average time the page take to load then read the content. But you will never be really sure the page is totally loaded.

Comment: Is it really this page you want to read? I think it's not the best example because it's depend on the time the servers will respond to the query.

Comment: yes it is that one, but how can i active the page w/o reading it ? if i use file_get_content for exemple, i can't wait before getting the content, same for cURL.

Comment: Ho ok i didn't understood the problem. file_get_content and cURL are querying the page directly right? For this my first idea is to load the page in an iframe then read the content of this iframe with JQuery.

Comment: damn.. i dont know JQuery at all, is there any way to do it in PHP ? I'm working on a script to read the page everynight, and check where my IP is blacklisted. I think to be able to get the list of it but only if i can read the page after all the processus are done. What is an iframe ?

Comment: I'm trying to implement this solution but i can't read the content of the iframe cause it's in another domain :/

Comment: @michael is there any way to make a stream/flux to a webpage ? i have no idea how to 'open' a webpage a read it after few seconds...

Comment: I'm sorry i don't know how to do it on PHP but what you want to do is called 'Site Scrapping' maybe you can search in this direction.

Comment: Thank you, i'll check for it, but i already know how to get the value i need, the only thing i dont know is how can i separate the execute action and the reading action on the same webpage (file_get_content for exemple will open and extract the page content.. what i need is to open, wait fews seconds and then extract the page content...) but i dont know how..